# Autopopulate answer in cell in Excel 2010 based on due date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there a formula that I can enter in Column G that will automatically add OVERDUE or IN PROGRESS based on the due date in Column B?

[image]

Comment: Have you actually tried to come up with something that would allow you to? You would probably need something like `if(G > NOW()){"Overdue"}`

Comment: You just need to use the conditional formatting tool in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `G12` use:

```
=if(B12>NOW(),"In Progress","Overdue")
```

And if you want to make so that the rows that are empty in column B should also be empty in column G, use this in `B12`:

```
=if(B12>NOW(),"In Progress",IF(B12="","","Overdue"))
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Is there a way to color code the cell too?

Comment: And...if there is no due date entered in Column B, how can I have the formula in Column G stay hidden until something is entered?

Comment: You can color code it based on its content using Conditional Formatting. I did a small clip on how I'm doing it https://streamable.com/0vhz2

Comment: Adding to my answer about the hidden question

Comment: Thank you so much, it would have taken me many days to figure this out, I appreciate your help!